# foundation clearing not working inside ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, zurb-foundation-5

I have the following inside an ajax call:

```
for(i = 0; i < data.images.length; i++){
  current.find('.img-ul').append("<li><a href='//" + data.images[i].prefix + data.images[i].suffix + "'><img src='//" + data.images[i].prefix + data.images[i].suffix + "'/></a></li>");
}

$(document).foundation();
$('.img-ul li').foundation('clearing', 'reflow');
```

I have tried different combinations, but when I click on the `a`, a new tab gets opened containing a bigger image of the thumbnail that I clicked on.

When clicking on the `a` tag it should open the overlay with the bigger images inside

Comment: try use $(document).foundation(); or $(document).foundation('reflow'); instead of .img-ul li

Comment: I have tried that too but it still doesn't work